# What is  Entity Field Type equivalent for symfony2 forms with propel?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

Entity Field Type in symfony 2 with Doctrine seems to be very nice feature. But I am using propel with symfony 2 and have been struggling to find a equivalent.

How can equivalent be achieved with symfony 2 forms with propel in case of entity field type? Is it that, it is only achievable with doctrine?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful!

[Propel and modelType for form][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394825/symfony2-forms-selected-value-in-dropdown-using-propel-modeltype

Answer (score 4):

You have `model` type in symfony [propel bridge](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Propel1/Form/Type/ModelType.php) Its equivalent of `entity` from doctrine.

You can check how to use it in the [propel documentation](http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/symfony2/mastering-symfony2-forms-with-propel.html#the_modeltype)
ex:

```
$builder->add('author', 'model', array(
   'class' => 'Acme\LibraryBundle\Model\Author',
));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but does the model type provide something like query_builder ( http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder ) and if does can you point me to the direction of an example?

Comment: You can pass \ModelCriteria as 'query' option... I think. I just read the type code from propel bridge. I do not know any other documentation (all I know is in my answer), but I am not propel expert. This is a little pain that we have entity type documented but not model one in official symfony documentation.